# C# 11 - What have we gained by adding IAdditionOperators to this method?

Tags: c#, .net-7.0, c#-11.0, .net-generic-math

I just upgraded Visual Studio 2022 to .NET7, which includes C# 11. I am interested in trying out the new [static abstract interface methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/static-virtual-interface-members), and so followed the tutorial there.

The article shows how to define `Point` and `Translation` records that use the new `IAdditionOperators<>` interface...

```cs
public record Translation<T>(T XOffset, T YOffset) where T : IAdditionOperators<T, T, T>;

public record Point<T>(T X, T Y) where T : IAdditionOperators<T, T, T> {
  public static Point<T> operator +(Point<T> left, Translation<T> right) =>
    left with { X = left.X + right.XOffset, Y = left.Y + right.YOffset };
}
```

This enables you to do this...

```cs
var pt = new Point<int>(3, 4);
var translate = new Translation<int>(5, 10);
var final = pt + translate;
```

Next it says...

> You can make this code more reusable by declaring that these types implement the appropriate arithmetic interfaces. The first change to make is to declare that `Point<T, T>` implements the `IAdditionOperators<Point<T>,` Translation, Point>`interface. The`Point`type makes use of different types for operands and the result. The`Point` type already implements an operator + with that signature, so adding the interface to the declaration is all you need:

```cs
public record Point<T>(T X, T Y) : IAdditionOperators<Point<T>, Translation<T>, Point<T>>
    where T : IAdditionOperators<T, T, T>
```

I'm struggling to understand this bit. Before you add the extra implementation part, you could add a `Translation` to a `Point`, as shown in the code above, and as explained in the last line of the paragraph I quoted.

Question 1: What have we gained by inserting `: IAdditionOperators<Point<T>, Translation<T>, Point<T>>` into the declaration of `Point`?

Question 2: In what way does this make the code more reusable? It doesn't seem to enable anything that didn't work before.

After that the article goes on to discuss the additive identity feature, which seems to be a separate point.

Can any explain what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For example it allows to define the following generic method and use it with `Point<T>` and `Translation<T>` (i.e. generically abstract over the addition operations):

```cs
public static T AddAll<T, TOther>(T t, List<TOther> c) where T : IAdditionOperators<T, TOther, T>
{
    foreach (var item in c)
    {
        t = t + item;
    }

    return t;
}
```

And usage (possible due to the interface introduction):

```cs
Point<int> p = AddAll(new Point<int>(1, 1), new List<Translation<int>>());
```

Comment: You could rename the type parameters to `TLeft` and `TRight` to gain in clarity.

Comment: Thanks, I see it now. Shame the article didn't show an example.